# Problem with UNION result in Yii2 Framework

Tags: yii2

```
$select = (new yii\db\Query())
            ->select('autori.IDAutore, autori.IParte, autori.IIParte, autori.Prefisso, autori.Qualificazione, count(autori.IDAutore) AS qta')
            ->from('autori')->where('1=1')
            ->innerJoin('bibliografie b', '
            b.RIDAutorePrinc1 = autori.IDAutore 
        ')->limit(10)->orderby('COUNT(*) DESC');
        
        $select1 = (new yii\db\Query())
            ->select('autori.IDAutore, autori.IParte, autori.IIParte, autori.Prefisso, autori.Qualificazione, count(autori.IDAutore) AS qta')
            ->from('autori')->where('1=1')
            ->innerJoin('bibliografie b', '
            b.RIDAutorePrinc2 = autori.IDAutore
        ')->limit(10)->orderby('COUNT(*) DESC');
      
$select->union($select1);

$autoreList = $select->groupby('autori.IDAutore')->limit(10)->all();
```

This will return:

```
Michael (10)
Michael(4)
```

I want: `Michael (14)`

Which is the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

union return sperated  rows  .. so you have two values
coul be you need   another join  condition of a single query instead of a union between two queries

```
$select = (new yii\db\Query())
            ->select('autori.IDAutore
                , autori.IParte
                , autori.IIParte
                , autori.Prefisso
                , autori.Qualificazione
                , count(autori.IDAutore) AS qta')
            ->from('autori')->where('1=1')
            ->innerJoin('bibliografie b', '
            b.RIDAutorePrinc1 = autori.IDAutore OR b.RIDAutorePrinc2 = autori.IDAutore
        ')->limit(10)->orderby('COUNT(*) DESC');
```

if you have performance problem for a complex query  you could try using pure sql and a sql command  eg:

```
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;
$q = " select t.IDAutore
    , t.IParte
    , t.IIParte
    , t.Prefisso
   , t.Qualificazione
   , sum( num_autori)
  from  (


select autori.IDAutore
    , autori.IParte
    , autori.IIParte
    , autori.Prefisso
   , autori.Qualificazione
   , count(autori.IDAutore)  num_autori
  from autori 
  inner join bibliografie b on  b.RIDAutorePrinc1 = autori.IDAutore  
  order by num_autori 
  limit 10 
  union 
select autori.IDAutore
    , autori.IParte
    , autori.IIParte
    , autori.Prefisso
   , autori.Qualificazione
   , count(autori.IDAutore)  num_autori
  from autori 
  inner join bibliografie b on  b.RIDAutorePrinc2 = autori.IDAutore  
  order by num_autori 
  limit 10 
 union 
  ....
  .....
  ....
select autori.IDAutore
    , autori.IParte
    , autori.IIParte
    , autori.Prefisso
   , autori.Qualificazione
   , count(autori.IDAutore)  num_autori
  from autori 
  inner join bibliografie b on  b.RIDAutorePrinc2 = autori.IDAutore  
  order by num_autori 
  limit 10 ) t 
 group by t.IDAutore
    , t.IParte
    , t.IIParte
    , t.Prefisso
   , t.Qualificazione"

$autoreListArray = $connection->createCommand($q)->queryAll();
```

$autoreListArray  is an array with resulting list aggreagted by autore  and with the sum of the single count in each select

Comment: I tried to write this query but the system became very slow, because I have multiples authors. With this query I have ten OR.

Comment: ten OR mean also ten UNION  and the performance should be the same  anyway ..  your question is about a right result not  about performance.. i hope my answer return the right result

Comment: So, how can I implement ten union for ten OR?

Comment: i don't understand your comment .. try explain your question in another way  ..

Comment: try update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result as tabular text  ..  is not clear what do you mean with "ten OR" ..you have then column for  "RIDAutorePrinc1.....10 " ????

Comment: I have RIDAutorePrinc1, RIDAutorePrinc2, RIDAutorePrinc3, RIDAutorePrinc4, RIDAutorePrinc5, RIDAutorePrinc6, RIDAutorePrinc7, RIDAutorePrinc8, RIDAutorePrinc9, RIDAutorePrinc10. Now, if I build a query with OR statement (like you suggest me) the system is too slow, beacuse the database is large. I need to optimaze this query. So I've built the union clause but the result is duplicate (Michael 10 and Michael 4, I want Michael 14)

Comment: @jackall90   answer  updated . with a suggestion  .. hope is useful ..

Comment: Ok I think this is the right way..but this give me this error : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias. Where is the problem? Thank you

Comment: be sure you have the an alias at the end of the subquery from ( .... ...   )   t